# What causes "ActivityThread: Schedule relaunch activity"?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

As the title says, I'm looking for the cause of `ActivityThread: Schedule relaunch activity: foo.bar.MyActivity` in my application log. I'm seeing this entry after `MyActivity.onResume()` but I'm not overriding that method and I'm not restarting the activity myself. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241476/oncreate-launches-twice-without-any-ui-changes) related to the log entry but I'm not issuing any network requests or doing anything complicated in `onCreate()`. There are no configuration changes in the log, either, that might explain the activity being restarted.
I can't reproduce this on my devices and I only know of one instance of it happening so it seems to be something that happens very sporadically. In short, does anyone know why Android will sometimes restart my activity with the message in the title?

Comment: Could you find out why it happened?

Answer (score 2):

This one can happens when configuration change when app in foreground.
I can reproduce it on Samsung and Pixel devices (not sure about other devices)

Example, you have this stack activities `A->B->C`.
And on `CActivity` , you have code to change configuration (eg: app theme) like

```
class ActivityC : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_change_theme).setOnClickListener {
            if(resources.configuration.uiMode andConfiguration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After you click on the button, those log will prints together

```
ActivityThread com.example.androidactivitiestest    I  Schedule relaunch activity: com.example.androidactivitiestest.test_relaunch.BActivity
ActivityThread com.example.androidactivitiestest    I  Schedule relaunch activity: com.example.androidactivitiestest.test_relaunch.AActivity
ActivityThread com.example.androidactivitiestest    I  Schedule relaunch activity: com.example.androidactivitiestest.test_relaunch.CActivity
```

Then, **ALL** activities will be detroyed then created **together**. An interesting here is `onResume` in both `AActivity` and `BActivity` will be trigged even those activities currently not visible to user

The above behaviour is different if I change Light/Dark theme from Setting while app is in background.
First, I don't see `Schedule relaunch activity` log.
Secondly, all activities **will not** destroy then create together after app move to foreground again.
C activity will destroy->create first after app go foreground, after closing C, B activity destroy->create, then after close B, A activity destroy->create

`Schedule relaunch activity` log also not print when system kill my app process in low memory (simulate by command). The activity recreation is similar to changing configuration while app in background except there is no `onDestroy`. `onDestroy` not trigger after I kill app process, and after move to foreground, all C,B,A activity will not call onDestroy before onCreate

In all above case, after the activity recreate, it is a different instance

Note that, on above demo, I don't set any `configChanges` for my Activity in `AndroidManifest`, so my activity always recreate after any configurations change

Comment: how to fix this..??

Comment: @SaurabhG I think it's not a bug, so we don't need to fix this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77982264/activitythreadschedule-relaunch-activityactivity-package
Please check this. @Linh

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening if the app is in the background for awhile, Android kills off the OS process hosting the app, and then the user returns to the app (selects it from the list of recent tasks, or just clicks on the app icon on the HOME screen again). Android will then create a new OS process for the app and relaunch the `Activity` that was on the top of the `Activity` stack.