# ActivityThread:Schedule relaunch activity:<Activity Package>

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

Activity in my application is getting relaunched automatically and expectedly and I am getting window leak exceptions because I have dialog showing during that time.
Below are the logs, Please check and guide what could be the reason for it and how could I resolve this issue.

**DialogHelper:325 -> Success overlay is shown**
20:02:44.963  I  dispatchDetachedFromWindow
20:02:44.966  D  Window{ce35688 u0
com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity}:
Setting back callback null
20:02:44.966  W  Input channel object 'ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
20:02:44.968  I  Reparenting to leash, surface=Surface(name=ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity)/@0x2867ed2, leashParent=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{3fcb7ba u0 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/.ui.MainActivity})/@0x6542ba3
20:02:44.969  I  id=4880 createSurf flag=24000, Surface(name=ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity)/@0x2867ed2 - animation-leash of window_animation#4880
20:02:44.969  D  makeSurface duration=1 leash=Surface(name=Surface(name=ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity)/@0x2867ed2 - animation-leash of window_animation)/@0x9615d35
20:02:44.986  I  CPUManager:44 -> Release CPU Lock
20:02:44.986  I  CPUManager:51 -> CPULockCount = -1
20:02:45.026  I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 95679(3893KB) AllocSpace objects, 26(1592KB) LOS objects, 36% free, 8198KB/12MB, paused 266us,165us total 351.576ms
20:02:45.042  I  **Schedule relaunch activity: com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity**
20:02:45.061  I  AuthFragment:62 -> On Create View
20:02:45.171  I  Reparenting to original parent: Surface(name=ActivityRecord{3fcb7ba u0 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/.ui.MainActivity})/@0x6542ba3, destroy=true, surface=Surface(name=ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity)/@0x2867ed2
20:02:45.173  I  Destroying surface Surface(name=com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity)/@0xc2efa58 called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:749 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:418 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroySurfaceUnchecked:3627 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroySurface:3601 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5179 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:200 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:5394 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onAnimationFinished:2
20:02:45.178  I  id=4871 removeFromCurrentState com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#4871 (108)
20:02:45.178  I  id=4870 removeFromCurrentState ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#4870 (108)
20:02:45.178  I  id=4880 removeFromCurrentState Surface(name=ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity)/@0x2867ed2 - animation-leash of window_animation#4880 (108)
20:02:45.178  I  Layer [com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#4871] hidden!! flag(1)
20:02:45.182  D  Display 4633128672291735937 HWC layers:
DEVICE | 0xe830c600 | 0100 | RGBA_8888    |    0.0    0.0  480.0  480.0 |    0    0  480  480 | com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#4863
SOLID_COLOR |              | 0000 |  Unknown  |    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 |    0    0  480  480 | Dim Layer for - Task=1667#4873
DEVICE | 0xe830ea00 | 0100 | RGBA_8888    |    9.0    9.0  489.0  489.0 |    0    0  480  480 | com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#487
20:02:45.191  I  id=4870 Removed ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#4870 (108)
20:02:45.191  I  id=4880 Removed Surface(name=ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity)/@0x2867ed2 - animation-leash of window_animation#4880 (108)
20:02:45.191  I  id=4871 Removed com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#4871 (108)
20:02:45.194  I  id=4880 Destroyed Surface(name=ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity)/@0x2867ed2 - animation-leash of window_animation#4880
20:02:45.194  I  id=4870 Destroyed ce35688 com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#4870
20:02:45.195  I  id=4871 Destroyed com.harman.dht.rcp_watch/com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity#4871
20:02:45.229  I  AuthFragment:79 -> authDetails.isForgotPin: false
20:02:45.237  W  A resource failed to call close.
20:02:45.238  W  A resource failed to call close.
**20:02:45.306  I  MainActivity:496 -> On Pause
20:02:45.342  I  MainActivity:526 -> On Destroy**
20:02:45.354  V  Recording user engagement, ms: 55113
20:02:45.370  E  **android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.harman.dht.rcp_watch.ui.MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@e81fdfb[MainActivity] that was originally added here**

Below is the code where I am getting this issue.
Please check and guide.

````
DialogHelper.showTwoButtonDialog(context,
                    LanguageUtil.getInstance().getTranslation("logout_button"),
                    LanguageUtil.getInstance().getTranslation("logout_message"),
                    needDismissAfterOk = false,
                    okAction = { logoutDialog ->
                        val progressDialog = DialogHelper.showProgressDialog(
                            logoutDialog.context,
                            LanguageUtil.getInstance().getTranslation("logout_progress_text"),)

                        applicationPreferences.setBoolean(PreferencesType.BlockBackKey, true)
                        Utils.viewModelScope(this@SettingsViewModel).launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

                            cpuManager.requestCPULock()

                            uploadManager.uploadVitals()
                            uploadManager.uploadWorkouts()
                            auditLoggerManager.sendAuditLogData()

                            loggerManager.sendLogs(true)
                            //Commenting the code since this functionality is not required currently.
                            //loggerManager.sendScreenshots()

                            eventManager.notify(
                                AuthenticationStatusChanged(
                                    AuthenticationStatusChanged.UserStatus.Logout
                                )
                            )

                            runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                applicationPreferences.setBoolean(PreferencesType.BlockBackKey, false)

                                DialogHelper.showSuccessOverlay(
                                    null, "", progressDialog.window?.decorView
                                ) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                                }
                                logoutDialog.dismiss()
                                navigationManager.navigate(
                                    R.id.loginOptionFragment,
                                    SimpleRecyclerViewFragmentDirections.actionLoginOptionFragmentToAuthFragment(
                                        AuthDetails(false)
                                    )
                                )
                            }

                            cpuManager.releaseCPULock()
                        }
                    })
            }
        }```
````